# Finitely generated ideals of the ring of smooth functions on a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, commutative-algebra, real-algebraic-geometry

My question refers to an exercise in "Topology of Real Algebraic Sets" by Akbulut and King. This exercise is about one of the possible definition of blow-up in a differential framework, more precisely:

Let $M$ be a real smooth manifold and $L\subset M$ a smooth proper submanifold of $M$. Define the ideal:

$\mathscr{I}_M^\infty(L)=\{f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M):f(x)=0\,\,\text{for every }x\in L\}$.

Then, $\mathscr{I}_M^\infty(L)$ is finitely generated.

I am not so used to the properties of $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ as a ring and I really do not understand where to use the hypothesis about the properness of the injection from $L$ to $M$. I am grateful to anyone will give me some hint, solution or reference about this exercise.

Comment: See [Malgrane preparation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malgrange_preparation_theorem).

Comment: Try with $M= \Bbb{R}^2$ and $L$ a curve, divide $L$ into finitely many simply connected pieces $L_j$, construct some smooth functions such that $\forall l\in L_j, f(l)=0,\nabla f(l)\ne 0$ and $\{x,\forall j, f_j(x)=0\}\subset L$ then $C^\infty(M)/(f_1,\ldots,f_J) =C^\infty(L)$

Comment: I am interested in your suggestion. I saw the Weierstrass preparation theorem during my previous courses in Algebraic Geometry but I am a bit confused about how to apply this result to my question. Can you clarify your hint? Thank you. @MoonLightSyzygy